# What is this Chrome debugger VM script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8

You can find this file by calling `dir(obj)` in the Chrome dev tools console and clicking the link display on the right pointing to where `dir` is defined in this file.

What are the details behind this file?

Is this the script that is part of Chrome's debugger or is it some interface with V8?

Why is there a 2007 Apple copyright at the top?

When I open this file the numeric identifier after VM is always different. Where does the VMXXXX identifier come from?

Are there anymore of these files publicly visible like this and, if so, how do you access them?

Thanks!

[image: Chrome debugger VM script]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This file is part of Dev Tools implementation, which resides within Blink source tree: [`Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js).

There is Apple copyright because Blink itself is fork of WebKit, at that copyright is retained from there.

`VMxyz` identifiers are generated by devtools themsevles for dynamically injected scripts that have no associated URL. See `addScript` method in [`Source/devtools/front_end/bindings/DefaultScriptMapping.js`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/devtools/front_end/bindings/DefaultScriptMapping.js#188)

DevTools have a lot of JavaScript code inside of them, especially when it comes to UI which is all HTML based. Just browse `Source/devtools/front_end/` folder in Blink Sources.